# How to deploy Firebase Cloud functions programmatically, to be run at a specific time?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, scheduled-tasks

Usually functions are deployed via CLI, calling the `firebase deploy -only functions:my_function`.

- **Is it possible to deploy functions programmatically (hence dynamically)?**

In my use case I would like to re-schedule a `PubSub` to **run after a specific amount of time**, relative to the current execution time, rather than regularly every time interval.
The same way as `setTimeout` would work (rather than a `setInterval`), but without having a process running and waiting to call the function.

What would be the drawbacks?
What would be alternative ways to achieve a similar result with what Firebase provides?

Answer (score 1):

You already deploy that Cloud Function programmatically by issuing a command.

Generally there's repeated and delayed execution available.

a) [Cloud Scheduler](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudscheduler) [`crontab`](https://crontab.guru) receives scheduled Pub/Sub events:

```
exports.cronjob = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 */12 * * *').onRun(async context => {
   ...
});
```

b) [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/tutorial-gcf#creating_the_task) may be better to schedule at a specific time.